# How to add firebase database rules without authentication?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

i want add Firebase Real-time database rules it is set to default and i cant use authentication because my app is already deployed with data in database.

please help, thank you

Comment: Leave the default rules. It is not mandatory to use Security Rules. However, your database will remain unsecured, and some malicious users might take advantage of that.

Comment: @alexmamo I'd argue that at least applying validation rules and restricting certain database nodes would reduce avenues for abuse - authentication doesn't have to be a part of those rules though.

Comment: @samthecodingman Yes, indeed sam.

Answer (score 14):

To grant any user complete read/write access to your Realtime Database (RTDB), you can use these global read/write access rules:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

These rules will allow anyone to read, write, delete or change the data in your database - **including deleting the entire database**. These rules will also trigger periodic emails from Firebase warning you that your rules are insecure.

---

Instead of using such wide-reaching rules, there are a number of ways you can tighten up your database to prevent such abuse.

Firebase Security Rules are [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics), their [API reference is here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database) and you can [manage them here](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/rules).

Because you have indicated that you aren't planning to use Firebase Authentication, I will omit those examples and instead refer you to the documentation for those examples. As you haven't provided any examples of data stored in your database, I will also be coming up with various examples around storing cars in a database.

---

Let's say your app contains a publicly accessible database of cars under `/cars` with the following shape:

```
interface Car {
  make: string,
  model: string,
  year: number,
  type: string
}
```

Instead of using the completely public rules above, we can instead make it so users can only read/write to the `/cars` node:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "cars": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

With the above rules, you can create, update, delete any node under `/cars`, but a read/write to `/trains` would be denied. This is because security rules  default to `false` (deny) unless defined otherwise. If a security rule would throw an error (syntax error, missing data, bad object type), it is treated as `false` (deny).

With the above rules, any user could create `/cars/someId/path` and fill it with heaps of irrelevant data.

To correct this, we can define the nodes under a dynamic node path (such as `cars/$carId`) and choose what fields will be read/writable:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "cars": {
      // any car is readable
      ".read": true,

      "$carId": {
        "make":  { ".write": true },
        "model": { ".write": true },
        "year":  { ".write": true },
        "type":  { ".write": true }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using these rules, you can now create and store a `Car` object in your database. You won't be able to add data to locations like `/cars/someId/path` but you can still add data to `/cars/someId/make/path` like before.

This is where data validation rules come in. We can ensure that the type of a node is what we expect (as long as it's a number, string or boolean):

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "cars": {
      // any car is readable
      ".read": true,

      "$carId": {
        "make":  { ".write": true, ".validate": "newData.isString()" },
        "model": { ".write": true, ".validate": "newData.isString()" },
        "year":  { ".write": true, ".validate": "newData.isNumber()" },
        "type":  { ".write": true, ".validate": "newData.isString()" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above rules enforce the types of each part of a `Car` object, but they don't make sure the entire `Car` object is present. To enforce validation on the children of a node, such as making sure the entire car object is present, we move the `".validate"` rule up one level:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "cars": {
      // any car is readable
      ".read": true,

      "$carId": {
        // a car object must be complete
        ".validate": "newData.child('make').isString() && newData.child('model').isString() && newData.child('year').isNumber() && newData.child('type').isString()",

        "make":  { ".write": true },
        "model": { ".write": true },
        "year":  { ".write": true },
        "type":  { ".write": true }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the above rules, you can now create/update/delete any cars stored under `/cars` as long as they look like a `Car` object.

---

Simply allowing complete write access may not be what you desire. By tweaking `".write": "true"`, we can apply additional restrictions on what data is allowed to be changed.

If we wanted to make it so you can only create/update a car, but not delete it, we can use:

```json
".write": "newData.exists()"
```

If we wanted to make it so you can only create a car, but not update/delete it, we can use:

```json
".write": "!data.exists()"
```

If we wanted to make it so you can only update an existing car, but not create/delete it, we can use:

```json
".write": "data.exists() && newData.exists()"
```

---

Using these building blocks, you should now be able to tighten your database without blocking your existing application.

Comment: You're killing me. Excellent answer, sam!