# Firebase rules warning - any user can read your entire database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I don't use google authentication. An app where I only show texts and images to users. I got a message today from firebase.

**Any user can read your entire database**

How can i solve this? I don't know about firebase rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

Comment: "I don't know about firebase rules." See https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules, https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security, https://stackoverflow.com/q/51392059, https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/insecure-rules

Comment: Because you aren't using authentication, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68411885/3068190) may also be worth reading.